# How to select data from two table in magento with same condition in custom table

Tags: magento-1.8, collection, sql

I have two table tbl_magazine, tbl_page ....
I need to select data form magazine like...
if magazine is enabled then also check magazine page is enable or not...
if magazine is enable and some pages of magazine is disable then only select acive table.

```
my table is
------------              

magazine  table

magazine_id
magazine_name
magazine_cover
status

page table


page_id
magazine_id
page_content
status
```

### I musing this query..

```
   public function getMagazine() {
        $current_magazine_id = Mage::registry('current_magazine_id');
        $id = $current_magazine_id['o'];
        Mage::unregister('current_magazine_id');

        if ($id) {

            $collection = Mage::getModel('magazine/page')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('magazine_id', $id)
                    ->addFieldToSelect('status', array('eq' => 'ENABLED'))
                     ->setOrder('page_id', 'ASC');
        } else {
            $defaultMagazine = Mage::getModel('magazine/display')->getCollection();
            $data = $defaultMagazine->getData();
            $defaultMagazineId = $data[0]['magazine_id'];
            $collection = Mage::getModel('magazine/page')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('magazine_id', $defaultMagazineId)
                    ->addFieldToSelect('status', array('eq' => 'ENABLED'))
                     ->setOrder('page_id', 'ASC');
        }
        return $collection;
    }
```

### my error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `magazine` AS `main_table` ORDER BY month ASC' at line 1
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about MySQL join queries. You might have more luck on Stackoverflow as this is not specifically Magento related

Comment: @SanderMangel i want to get this in custom magento module....this is not off topic

Comment: Ok so what do you have so far on code? Any snippets we could start answering the question from? What you're asking is quite broad

Comment: @Marius THis is not off topic question

Comment: @SanderMangel  I edited my question

Comment: @user3623126. Now that you provided some data is not off topic anymore. But with the original content, it was.

Comment: @Marius can you pls solved this...

Answer (score 1):

I used this and currently its working fine...

```
public function getMagazine() {
    $current_magazine_id = Mage::registry('current_magazine_id');
    $id = $current_magazine_id['o'];
    Mage::unregister('current_magazine_id');

    if ($id) {

        $collection = Mage::getModel('magazine/page')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToSelect('*')
                ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => 'ENABLED'))
                ->addFieldToFilter('magazine_id', array('in' => $id));
        $collection->getSelect()->order('page_id ASC');
    } else {
        $defaultMagazine = Mage::getModel('magazine/display')->getCollection();
        $data = $defaultMagazine->getData();

        $defaultMagazineId = $data[0]['magazine_id'];
        $collection = Mage::getModel('magazine/page')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToSelect('*')
                ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => 'ENABLED'))
                ->addFieldToFilter('magazine_id', array('in' => $defaultMagazineId));
        $collection->getSelect()->order('page_id ASC');
    }
    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: feel free to accept this answer if it is now working

Answer (score 0):

Taking the code from your answer what you could do is simply write a getId function that checks the current magazine and then gets the default if it is not set. Then I think you will remove your code duplication.

```
private function getMagazineId() {
    $current_magazine_id = Mage::registry('current_magazine_id');
    if ($current_magazine_id !== null) {
        $id = $current_magazine_id['o'];
        Mage::unregister('current_magazine_id');
    } else {
        $defaultMagazine = Mage::getModel('magazine/display')->getCollection();
        $data = $defaultMagazine->getData();

        $id = $data[0]['magazine_id'];
    }
    return $id;
}

public function getMagazine() {
    $collection = Mage::getModel('magazine/page')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => 'ENABLED'))
        ->addFieldToFilter('magazine_id', array('in' => $this->getMagazineId()));
    $collection->getSelect()->order('page_id ASC');
    return $collection;
}
```

Not really sure if this is the "best" way but will remove the duplication from your original answer.